# How to add target to a closed initialisation of UIImageView

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

This is the code for the initialisation UIImageView

```
  var supportButton: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Menu3")
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill

    //Add target here??

    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return imageView
}()
```

Following dosen't work because there is no self:

```
   imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UIGestureRecognizer(target: self(), action: #selector(Support)))
```

Comment: You cannot add the target like that, because `self` hasn't been initialized. All you probably need to do is move that line into `viewDidLoad` for things to work. (this has nothing to do with `UIImageView`, as the same thing would happen with a `UIButton`. That's a drawback to this style of coding in Swift. An alternative would be to create a extension to `UIIamgeView` that has a `convenience init` and pass both `self` and the `#selector` in - but you'll still need to add code in `viewDidLoad`.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are declaring a property of a ViewController you need to use `self` instead of `self()`

Here's an example

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let supportButton: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Menu3")
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        let gestureRecognizer = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.didTouchSupport(gestureRecognizer:)))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return imageView
    }()

    @objc func didTouchSupport(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {

    }
}
```

### Update

The following code should answer the comments you posted below.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! Cell
        cell.delegate = self
        return cell
    }
}

extension TableViewController: CellDelegate {
    func didTapSupport() {
        // TODO: your custom code goes here
    }
}

protocol CellDelegate {
    func didTapSupport()
}

class Cell: UITableViewCell {

    var delegate: CellDelegate?

    let supportButton: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "Menu3")
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(Cell.didTouchSupport(gestureRecognizer:)))
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return imageView
    }()

    @objc func didTouchSupport(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {
        delegate?.didTapSupport()
    }
}
```

Comment: My viewcontroller cant find the function... @Luca Angeletti

Comment: Also the "ViewController" I'm using is a class for the cells in my tableView

Comment: I tried to print a test in the costumn code part but had no result. I'm trying to create like a like button on instagram in a tableView, maybe this is not the best approach. What do you think?